# SQL WHERE IN , multiple conditions restricted to record

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When creating an scd2 table, I am trying to identify the values `IN` the Transient table, as to identify records that contain the same id_A and id_B on the record level. i.e. I do not want it to mix in match. With this `WHERE IN` logic, is the computer looking at these conditions on a row by row basis?

```
UPDATE test_table AS a
SET a.current_record = FALSE
WHERE a.id_A IN (
        SELECT id_A
        FROM Transient_Table
        )
    AND a.id_B IN (
        SELECT a.id_B PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE
        FROM Transient_Table
        );
```

Comment: Yes. Also, which RDBMS are you using? This query could be probably rewritten as `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... JOIN ...` using an explicit join between test_table and transient_table (a.id_A = b.id_A and a.id_B = b.id_B)

Comment: Snowflake, could you write that out as an answer (and the join) and so I can give you the points

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
update a
  set a.current_record = FALSE -- Not sure your RDBMS honors FALSE , in SQL Server it does not. So, update this accordingly.
  from test_table as a
  join Transient_Table as t on a.id_A = t.id_A and a.id_B = t.id_B
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything SQL does is row by row. So it goes to the first row and makes sure condition 1 is satisfied and then condition 2 is satisfied. If BOTH are satisfied, SQL includes the row.

I believe this is the correct syntax for Snowflake. Not sure if you can add aliases:

```
update test_table
set current_record = false
from Transient_Table
where test_table.id_A = transient_table.id_A and test_table.id_B = transient_table.id_B;
```